# RAFT election restrictions

Tags: replication, distributed, voting-system, consensus, raft

I'm learning Raft from scratch with the [Raft paper](https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf), and I can't understand the leader election process. I read in 5.4.1 that a leader needs to have in its log all the committed entries of the cluster:

> *Raft uses a simpler approach where it guarantees that all the committed entries from previous terms are present on each new leader
>   from the moment of its election, without the need to transfer those
>   entries to the leader.*
>
> *Raft uses the voting process to prevent a candidate from winning an election unless its log contains all committed entries.*

But later on, it is said that a candidate holds all the committed entries if it is at least as up-to-date as any other log in the majority. And the mechanism to determine this up-to-date is comparing the index and term of the last entries. The log with the higher term on the last entry will be more up-to-date.

Couldn't that lead to a situation in which a leader was elected without all previous committed entries? For instance:

[image]

In this case, if server 4 failed, server 2 could become leader, since it has an entry with a bigger term than the majority. But it wouldn't have in its log the two committed entries from term 2. Is that right? I am misunderstanding something but I can get what it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, how did the logs get to that state in the first place? It's not possible.

So, it looks like:

```
* Server 2 is leader for term 1
* Server 1 is leader for term 2
* Server 2 (perhaps) is leader for term 3
* Server 4 is leader for term 4
```

But server 2 couldn't have been the leader for term 3 because it couldn't get votes based on the fact the last entry in its log would have been from term 1. If another server was leader for term 3, it must have written an entry for term 3 in its log if there's an entry from term 3 in server 2's log. But if there was another entry for term 3 in another server's log, a server with entries from term 2 could not have been elected since there would only be two of those. Even if server 3 had entries from term 2 in its log, it couldn't have been elected at that position because there would still be three other servers with entries from term 2 at higher indexes in the log.

So, I think you need to describe how the cluster got in a state in which server 2 could have won an election that would put an entry from term 3 in its log at index 4. It's important to note that the election protocol is not just about terms, it's also about indices. If two servers' last entries have the same term, the server with the greater last index is considered more up to date.

Comment: I understand what you say, but my question is different. For instance, in the example you just set out, what I don't get is how could server 2 become leader for term 3 (supposedly) when probably the two first entries of term 2 were committed.

Comment: Server 2 could not become the leader for term 3. During an election, server 2's last term would be 1. Server 2 cannot be elected for term 3 because a majority of the other servers - server 1, 4, and 5 - have entries from term 2 in their logs. That is my point. This history is not possible.

Comment: Ok, so just to make sure I get it: the restriction that says that to become a leader a server must have all the committed entries is then implemented indirectly by studying the terms and indexs of the other logs during the voting. Not by any variable that says which entries are committed? Is that correct?

Comment: That's right. That the leader has all prior committed entries is a property of the election algorithm, but the actual `commitIndex` is in no way involved in the election algorithm. In fact, it *is* entirely possible for a leader to get elected without some entries that have been stored on a majority of servers. This is why commitment is not always determined by counting replicas and it's why leaders must commit an entry from their current term to call entries from past terms committed. See figure 8 in the Raft paper for an explanation of this.

Comment: Votes are determined solely based on a follower's last term, and if terms are equal it's last index. Commit indexes are held in memory and are wiped out after a crash, but servers can still accurately vote when they recover based on their log index/term.